# Argument 1234 in numpy.random.RandomState

Tags: python, numpy, random

I came across this line in a code :

`numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)`

I've seen in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) that `numpy.random.RandomState` is sort of a library in which one can find many probability distributions. I don't understand the argument 1234 however. Someone please explain ?

Comment: It's the [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) for the pseudorandom number generator. Basically, if you give it the same seed, it will always generate the same sequence of "random" (actually pseudorandom) numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement:

```
r = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
```

creates a [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) random number generator, and binds it to the name r. The Mersenne Twister is a very useful algorithm for generating pseudorandom numbers that are suitable for large scale scientific simulations.

The parameter you pass to `numpy.random.RandomState` is the seed for the generator, which specifies the starting point for a sequence of pseudorandom numbers. If you seed two different generators with the same thing, you will get the same sequence of results. The uniform() method returns a pseudorandom number between zero and one. Observe:

```
>>> import numpy.random
>>> r = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
>>> r.uniform()
0.1915194503788923
>>> r.uniform()
0.6221087710398319

>>> r2 = numpy.random.RandomState(1235)
>>> r2.uniform()
0.9537625822517408
>>> r2.uniform()
0.9921264707372405

>>> r3 = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
>>> r3.uniform()
0.1915194503788923
>>> r3.uniform()
0.6221087710398319
```

Saving the value of the seed you used to construct the `RandomState` object will allow you to rerun a simulation with the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers later.

Answer (score 1):

`RandomState` is a pseudorandom number generator, which means that it can't generate truly random numbers, but only numbers that "look" random. To do this, you need to give it some initial "seed" that it can use to generate the numbers.

The argument you're referring to is the seed; it should preferrably be unique to each function call, since if it's called with the same seed twice, it will generate the exact same sequence of numbers.